# Can i create custom attribute and tags in trx file?

Tags: trx

I have a requirement wherein i need to write some custom info, say "Bug id" on each of the unit tests i have written using MS Unit test. After doing this, I want the info in trx file in a custom tag say,  Bug id : 1234  under  tag.
Currently, it writes the info to trx file in  tag in a para graphic manner under  tag.
I further need to make use of this Bug id in my business logic. but problem is, the  tag already contains some other info(related to text executions) in para graphic manner and it just appends the Bug id to the existing paragraph.

The information looks something like this:

```
<Output>
  <Stdout>
    ksnvfvnfnnfnvvffvkvfd
    mvomovodmdmmdv
    Bug id : 1234
  </Stdout>
</Output>
```

And here is what I would like to have:

```
<Output>
  <Stdout>
    ksnvfvnfnnfnvvffvkvfd
    mvomovodmdmmdv
   <CustomTag> Bug id : 1234</CustomTag> 
  </Stdout>
</Output>`
```